# How to get (condition) previous candle high and low

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am making an indicator showing swing lows and highs (3 bar pattern where a swing high has lower candle from each side and swing low has higher candle from each side)

I made it but I want to make an alert on when it's breached. As you can see from code the actual high or low is made after swing is formed. I display correctly swing by adding (offset-2). But alert triggers at actual swing high/low.

Q: How to get second previous candles high/low?

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Fractals Alerts', shorttitle='Fractals Alerts', overlay=true)

n = input.int(title='Periods', defval=2, minval=2)

//High(n-1) < High(n)
//High(n + 1) < High(n)

upFractal = high[n - 1] < high[n] and high[n + 1] < high[n]

//Low(n-1) > Low(n)
//Low(n + 1) > Low(n)

dnFractal = low[n - 1] > low[n] and low[n + 1] > low[n]

//make a shape

plotshape(upFractal, "High Broken", shape.xcross, location.abovebar, offset=-2, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
plotshape(dnFractal, "Low Broken", shape.xcross, location.belowbar, offset=-2, color=color.new(color.red, 0))

//get value high/low from fractals

upfractalhigh = ta.valuewhen(upFractal, high, 0)
upfractalbroke = (close > upfractalhigh)

//ignore//plotshape(frhitr, "Fractal High", shape.cross, location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green, 0))

//set condition

dnfractallow = ta.valuewhen(dnFractal, low, 0)
dnfractalbroke = (close < dnfractallow)

//Alerts

alertcondition(upfractalbroke, "high brake", "High Broken")
alertcondition(dnfractalbroke, "low brake", "Low Broken")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting project!

I'm not sure I've understood what you're looking for, exactly, but I think I've been able to map the previous swing high's peak (or the previous swing low's trough). I've plotted it with a step line, which you should be able to use to trigger your alerts.

[Here's an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03KJR.png)

I added text and symbols that trigger whenever the previous fractal's broken, just so I could see what was going on. You'll find I've changed a few variable names and things, too.

Let me know if the code's any use.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Fractals Alerts', shorttitle='Fractals Alerts', overlay=true)

n = input.int(title='Periods', defval=2, minval=2)

upFractal = high[n - 1] < high[n] and high[n + 1] < high[n]
dnFractal = low[n - 1] > low[n] and low[n + 1] > low[n]
plotshape(upFractal, "SH", shape.circle, location.abovebar, offset=-2, color=color.new(color.green, 0))
plotshape(dnFractal, "SL", shape.circle, location.belowbar, offset=-2, color=color.new(color.red, 0))

ufh = ta.valuewhen(upFractal, ta.highest(3), 0)
dfl = ta.valuewhen(dnFractal, ta.lowest(3), 0)

sh_broke = ta.crossover(high, ufh)
sl_broke = ta.crossunder(low, dfl), 
plotshape(sl_broke, "Break Down!", shape.arrowdown, location.belowbar, text="Break!", offset=0, color=color.new(color.black, 0))
plotshape(sh_broke, "Break Up!", shape.arrowup, location.abovebar, text="Break!", offset=0, color=color.new(color.black, 0))

plot(upFractal ? ufh: na, "High Broken", style=plot.style_stepline, offset=-2, color=color.new(color.green, 0))
plot(dfl, "Low Broken",style=plot.style_stepline, offset=-2, color=color.new(color.red, 0))

alertcondition(sh_broke, "SH Broken", "SH Broken")
alertcondition(sl_broke, "SL Broken", "SL Broken")
```

Comment: Amazing Matt! Thank you so so much! It's working ALMOST as I wanted it to work. I am being notified about break of Fractal but not always. There's a case if fractal is being broken on the 0 candle *see example* [link](https://prnt.sc/lq5igSgyFIZS) it's not identified as a break of fractal. And it's logical - because Fractal itself is formed on that candle. I tried changing defval to 1 but now the break is identified while the fractal is not formed (still forming 3rd candle) I wonder if it's possible to trigger the fractal once the 3rd candle is printed, not while it's forming? Thank you

Comment: Glad it was helpful! And yes - I see your problem. Have you solved it? If I get a spare few minutes today I'll take another look.

Comment: Unfortunately.. I am not a programmer so it's quite difficult to find useful info and solve everything hah. will try to drop another question in this forum with new code and new problem. but please let me know if you will have time if you looked at it again. Appreciate that!